# Determine when create-react-app updates stylesheets

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `window.getComputedStyle` to dynamically read values form my styleshseets. For development purposes I would like to find a way to trigger my logic to rerun when the stylesheets are automatically updated (updates triggered by edits). I'd prefer not to eject the project.

Ideally there would be a global variable that webpack updates in the background when an update occurs. Does that exist? Are there any simple solutions here?

Comment: You can't do without ejecting, and without touching on a custom webpack-dev-server, because you would need to attach this logic to one of the compiler hooks to rerun this when it had compiled the sources. WHich is not possible to be done without ejecting

Answer (score 0):

I've went ahead and wrote a wrapper function around `window.getComputedStyle`. When in development this wrapper function will keep track of all styles I am using. Using  `window.requestAnimationFrame` it will continuously poll all the used styles to determine if there was a change. If there is, it will trigger for the logic to be rerun. It's a hack but what else are dev environments for.